# Save stored procedure output to new table without repeating table type

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, hana

I want to call an existing procedure and store its table-typed `OUT` parameters to new physical tables, without having to repeat the definitions of the output types when creating the new tables. For example, if the procedure were

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MYPROC
     (IN X INTEGER, OUT Y TABLE(A INTEGER, B DOUBLE, C NVARCHAR(25)))
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT AS BEGIN
...
END;
```

I would want to create a physical table for the output without repeating the `(A INTEGER, B DOUBLE, C NVARCHAR(25))` part.

If I already had a table with the structure I want my result to have, I could `CREATE TABLE MY_OUTPUT LIKE EXISTING_TABLE`, but I don't.

If I already had a named type defined for the procedure's output type, I could create my table based on that type, but I don't.

If it were a subquery instead of a procedure output parameter, I could `CREATE TABLE MY_OUTPUT AS (<subquery>)`, but it's not a subquery, and I don't know how to express it as a subquery. Also, there could be multiple output parameters, and I don't know how you'd make this work with multiple output parameters.

In my specific case, the functions come from the [SAP HANA Predictive Analysis Library](https://help.sap.com/viewer/2cfbc5cf2bc14f028cfbe2a2bba60a50/2.0.02/en-US/c9eeed704f3f4ec39441434db8a874ad.html), so I don't have the option of changing how the functions are defined. Additionally, I suspect that PAL's unusually flexible handling of parameter types might prevent me from using solutions that would work for ordinary SQLScript procedures, but I'm still interested in solutions that would work for regular procedures, even if they fail on PAL.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, with limitations, to do this by using a SQLScript [anonymous block](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.03/en-US/dec9d68044bd49bcbb45c990ba49c81d.html):

```
DO BEGIN
CALL MYPROC(5, Y);
CREATE TABLE BLAH AS (SELECT * FROM :Y);
END;
```

We store the output to a table variable in the anonymous block, then create a physical table with data taken from the table variable. This even works with PAL! It's a lot of typing, though.

The limitation I've found is that the body of an anonymous block can't refer to local temporary tables created outside the anonymous block, so it's awkward to pass local temporary tables to the procedure this way. It's possible to do it anyway by passing the local temporary table as a parameter to the anonymous block itself, but that requires writing out the type of the local temporary table, and we were trying to avoid writing table types manually.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to use your database tables as output parameter types.

In my default schema, I have a database table named CITY

I can create a stored procedure as follows using the table as output parameter type

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyCityList (
    OUT CITYLIST CITY
)
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT 
AS 
BEGIN

CITYLIST = SELECT * FROM CITY;

END;
```

After procedure is created, you can execute it as follows

```
do
begin

declare myList CITY;
call MyCityList(:myList);
select * from :myList;

end;
```

Here is the result where the output data is in a database table format, namely as CITY table

[image]

I hope this answers your question,

- Update after first comment
  If the scenario is the opposite as mentioned in the first comment, you can query system view [PROCEDURE_PARAMETER_COLUMNS](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/3d028423c65b44bb8c34971bf4af1e1d.html) and create dynamic SQL statements that will generate tables with definitions in procedure table type parameters

Here is the SQL query

```
select 
parameter_name,
'CREATE Column Table ' || 
procedure_name || '_' 
|| parameter_name || ' ( ' || 

string_agg(
    column_name || ' ' || 
    data_type_name || 
    case when data_type_name = 'INTEGER' then '' else
    '(' || length || ')'
    end

    , ',' 
) || ' );'

from PROCEDURE_PARAMETER_COLUMNS 
where 
    schema_name = 'A00077387'
group by procedure_name, parameter_name
```

You need to replace the WHERE clause according to your case.
Each line will have such an output

```
CREATE Column Table LISTCITIESBYCOUNTRYID_CITYLIST ( CITYID INTEGER,NAME NVARCHAR(40) );
```

The format for table name is concatenation of procedure name and parameter name

One last note, some data types integer, decimal, etc requires special code like excluding length or adding of scale , etc. Some are not handled in this SQL.
I'll try to enhance the query soon and publish an update

Comment: Other way around - I have a procedure, and I want to create tables matching the procedure's output types.

Comment: PROCEDURE_PARAMETER_COLUMNS system view has the colum information for parameters of any stored procedure, you need to create a dynamic SQL for creating these as table in related schema